# regexp: non-empty line followed by "From "

Tags: regular-expression, maildir, pcregrep

I'm in the process of migrating my Mbox format emails to the Maildir format.
To this end I use `mb2md` which works great.

Nevertheless I've just come to realize that sometimes in my Mbox folders a blank line does not appear right before the "From " lines as it should, leading mb2md to not detect what follows as being a new email.

That's why out of a Mbox folder of 64 emails I end up with a Maildir of 32 emails...

I'm trying to use `pcregrep` to spot those cases but have a hard time figuring out the right regexp for detecting: a non-empty line followed by "From ".

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it would just be:

```
pcregrep -Mn '.\nFrom ' myfile
```

You could also pre-process the bogus mbox with `formail -es` which would add the missing lines.